# object detection yolo 5 api

Tags: artificial-intelligence, object-detection-api

[I got a ready-made model from the RoboFlow website to identify the garbage, and I added a variable to identify the percentage of the garbage, but I want to link it to the application to make an upload for the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7FLC.png)